# RxSwift Binding to UITable from a Variable

Tags: rx-swift

In RxSwift, do you know why I am not getting any values in this tableView?
Note: allTable is the UITableView

```
    var strList: Variable<[String]>?

    let disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

    strList?.value.append("111")
    strList?.value.append("222")
    strList?.value.append("333")

    strList?.asObservable()
        .bindTo(
            allTable.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)
        ){  (row, item, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = item
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Can you add the initialisation for `strList`? As is, strList is `nil` and all the code after the question marks is skipped because of this.

Comment: How do I initialise a RxSwift Variable?

Comment: `let strList = Variable(["abc", "dce"])`

Comment: Yes, but I still don't get anything in bindto. Do I have to do some kind of mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the creating of `disposeBag` outside of the function

```
let disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

var strList: Variable<[String]>?

func subscribeToStrList() {
    strList?.value.append("111")
    strList?.value.append("222")
    strList?.value.append("333")

    strList?.asObservable()
        .bindTo(
            allTable.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)
        ){  (row, item, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = item
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Otherwise, when the function exits, the subscription is disposed of.

Comment: That was well spotted! Thanks.